# BST toString in linear time

Tags: java

how can i write a linear-time toString() method for BST that uses StringBuilder?
i just want to know how to start atleast

Comment: BST being "binary search tree"?  Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Since this sounds like homework, I'll give just a hint to start: Use recursion, inorder tree traversal, and a single StringBuilder instance.

Comment: Yes, you would do that once at the end, to return a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to pass the StringBuilder in and also have it be the return value.

the basic principle that comes to mind is

```
// primary method
String toString(BSTNode node) {
    return toString0(node, new StringBuilder()).toString();
}

/**
 * assume BSTNode has toString implemented already.
 */
private StringBuilder toString(BSTNode node, StringBuilder result) {
    if(node == null) return result;
    result.append(node);
    toString(node.left,result);
    toString(node.right,result);
    return result;
}
```

Then you can simply call toString on the root of the tree to get everything in it.

Now, I haven't done much here, and I would not be surprised if there's a special case that's missing or something, but this basic approach should be sufficient.

Comment: thanx very much. now i know what to do. i knew the recursion part. but did'nt know how i was going to actualy save and print every node's value. tanx again

Comment: This is the basic layout of every recursive function. 1) Base case. 2) some work. 3) the recursion. In this case, we also return a result up the chain, which is a common (but not required) occurrence. Note that they need not necessarily appear in that order (although I believe the base case comes first in almost all cases. I can't think of any offhand where it doesn't.)

Comment: i dont understand the append part?

Comment: is'nt it suppose to be node.item?

Comment: Well, I'm sure there will. I was assuming your BSTNode has a `toString()` method implemented. This would give you whatever you needed, depending on the node. Perhaps it does `return this.item.toString()` or something?